# What do you call a psychologist who works with the criminally insane?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-requests, adjectives, psycholinguistics

I was just thinking about Harley Quinn and how she works in Arkham Asylum and it got me wondering, what type of psychologist works with criminals (like gives them therapy) who suffer from a mental health disorder at a maximum security mental hospital/asylum. An example would be I work Has a -type- psychologist at Arkham Asykum which is a maximum security mental hospital.

Comment: [What Does a Criminal Psychologist Do?](https://www.verywell.com/criminal-psychologist-a-career-profile-2795649) *A criminal psychologist is a professional that studies the behaviors and thoughts of criminals.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does a criminal psychologist give therapy to them though?

Comment: @FumbleFingers did you get my previous comment? Sorry to be annoying.

Comment: An *optimist* ?

Comment: Maybe a *forensic psychologist*...

Comment: Jaydan Osborne - to the extent that a *psychologist* might provide therapy, I suppose so. But as you can see, the definition I gave talks about *studying* them, not therapizing them. So maybe if you want to be more explicit about the role, you could say you're a [psychotherapist.](https://www.prospects.ac.uk/job-profiles/psychotherapist)

Comment: "In technical terminology... he's a loon." – [Dr Silberman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earl_Boen), Criminal Psychologist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to elevate my earlier comment and offer as a definitive answer the term ***Forensic Psychologist***, which *Psychology Today* defines this way:

> Forensic psychologists are most commonly licensed psychologists who specialize in applying psychological knowledge to legal matters, both in the criminal and civil arenas.

See the [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/witness/201409/forensic-psychology-is-it-the-career-me) here.

(Telephoning a family member who does this sort of work confirmed my earlier theory: *"What* are *you, anyway?" "Officially, I'm a forensic psychologist."* (Bada boom.) )

Answer (score 1):

It seems like "prison psychologist" is a term that might be what you're looking for.

http://www.apa.org/monitor/2008/04/job-prison.aspx